# Selectively ignore a file when preparing docker images

Tags: python, docker

Part of my Dockerfile is as follows:

```
COPY dependencies/mylib-0.5-py3-none-any.whl mylib-0.5-py3-none-any.whl
RUN pip install mylib-0.5-py3-none-any.whl && rm mylib-0.5-py3-none-any.whl

COPY . /app
```

I do not want the wheel in the docker image ...

But `COPY .` will copy it ...

Unless I specify that I do not want it to be copied by putting it in the `.dockerignore` ...

But then the first `COPY` command will not work.

Is there a way out of this Catch-22?

Comment: is that because the whl file is large and you want to optimise the final image size?

Comment: @Thomasleveil, yes, and because once installed the wheel has no reason to exist anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may just want to remove the file after the final `COPY`?

```
COPY dependencies/mylib-0.5-py3-none-any.whl mylib-0.5-py3-none-any.whl
RUN pip install mylib-0.5-py3-none-any.whl && rm mylib-0.5-py3-none-any.whl
COPY . /app

RUN rm /app/dependencies/mylib-0.5-py3-none-any.whl
```

Using `rm /app/dependencies/mylib-0.5-py3-none-any.whl` because it will be copied relative to its location in the source directory.

Futher, I guess you could then shorten this bit down to the following:

```
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install dependencies/mylib-0.5-py3-none-any.whl \
  && rm dependencies/mylib-0.5-py3-none-any.whl
```

You might already have the `WORKDIR` set, otherwise you would have to change the install and rm commands a bit.

Comment: I'm afraid the `COPY dependencies/mylib-0.5-py3-none-any.whl mylib-0.5-py3-none-any.whl` will create a layer in the final image, and having `RUN rm /app/dependencies/mylib-0.5-py3-none-any.whl` won't change anything to the final image size. Run `docker history <your image>` to list all layers